# Kernel Crash with following code to clear process cache in Linux kernel

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, x86

I am doing a Linux kernel module to cleanup a process cache.
Below is the code I am using to do that.

```
static void clear_process_cache(struct task_struct *p)
{
        struct mm_struct *mm;
        struct vm_area_struct *vma;
        struct page *page;
        char *my_page_address;
        unsigned long uaddr, paddr;
        long res;
        unsigned int level;
        pte_t *pte;

        mm = p->mm;
        for (vma = mm->mmap; vma; vma = vma->vm_next) {
                for(uaddr = vma->vm_start; uaddr < vma->vm_end; uaddr += PAGE_SIZE) {
                        down_read(&p->mm->mmap_sem);
                        res = get_user_pages(p, mm, uaddr, 1, 0, 1, &page, NULL);
                        if (res == 1) {
                               my_page_address = kmap(page);
                               paddr = (unsigned long)page_address(page);
                               pte = lookup_address(paddr, &level);
                               if (pte && (pte_val(*pte) &_PAGE_PRESENT)) {
                                       clflush_cache_range(my_page_address, PAGE_SIZE);
                               }   
                               kunmap(page);
                               put_page(page);
                       }   
                       up_read(&p->mm->mmap_sem);
                }   
        }   
}
```

When the code is called intensively, the Linux kernel crashed.
I checked my code, but could NOT find why it caused kernel crash.
Would you like to help on it, or is there any other high performance way to do that ??

Here is the crash dump.

```
[  391.693385] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
[  391.694435] Modules linked in: xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp bridge stp llc ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock kvm_intel kvm irqbypass vmw_balloon input_leds joydev serio_raw shpchp vmw_vmci i2c_piix4 mac_hid ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_sa ib_mad ib_core ib_addr iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi autofs4 btrfs raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper vmwgfx ablk_helper
[  391.702930]  cryptd ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea psmouse sysfillrect pata_acpi sysimgblt mptspi fb_sys_fops mptscsih drm mptbase vmxnet3 scsi_transport_spi floppy fjes
[  391.705034] CPU: 3 PID: 1716 Comm: java Not tainted 4.4.131 #4
[  391.706080] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 07/28/2017
[  391.708180] task: ffff88042607c600 ti: ffff8804292b8000 task.ti: ffff8804292b8000
[  391.709244] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff811a34dc>]  [<ffffffff811a34dc>] put_compound_page+0x5c/0x1b0
[  391.710358] RSP: 0000:ffff8804292bbcc8  EFLAGS: 00210202
[  391.711439] RAX: 00d0a78b4c535441 RBX: ffffffff810dc4f9 RCX: 000507e043713000
[  391.712523] RDX: ffff8804292bbd44 RSI: 000507e043713000 RDI: ffffffff810dc4f9
[  391.713586] RBP: ffff8804292bbcd8 R08: ffff880002213cf0 R09: 00003ffffffff000
[  391.714653] R10: 0000000000000080 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 00d0a78b4c535440
[  391.715712] R13: 0000160000000000 R14: ffff8804292bbd88 R15: ffffffff810dc4f9
[  391.716764] FS:  00007fb138d5b700(0000) GS:ffff88042d6c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  391.717829] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  391.718877] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000000351d1000 CR4: 00000000001606f0
[  391.719972] Stack:
[  391.720993]  ffffffff810dc4f9 ffff880000000000 ffff8804292bbcf0 ffffffff811a364d
[  391.722055]  ffff8804292bbdc8 ffff8804292bbdf8 ffffffff8102e21e ffff8804292bbd48
[  391.723122]  0000000000000000 ffff88042607c600 ffff880429e6ac00 ffff880425e9f388
[  391.724165] Call Trace:
[  391.725190]  [<ffffffff810dc4f9>] ? vprintk_default+0x29/0x40
[  391.726222]  [<ffffffff811a364d>] put_page+0x1d/0x50
[  391.727259]  [<ffffffff8102e21e>] clear_process_cache+0x11e/0x1f0
[  391.728298]  [<ffffffff810dc4f9>] ? vprintk_default+0x29/0x40
[  391.729318]  [<ffffffff811918d0>] ? printk+0x5a/0x76
[  391.730328]  [<ffffffff8102e93d>] do_signal+0x20d/0x770
[  391.731310]  [<ffffffff81193459>] ? unlock_page+0x69/0x70
[  391.732297]  [<ffffffff811972c0>] ? __probe_kernel_read+0x40/0x90
[  391.733271]  [<ffffffff8106d3c3>] ? bad_area+0x43/0x50
[  391.734220]  [<ffffffff810034fc>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x8c/0xd0
[  391.735143]  [<ffffffff81003c26>] prepare_exit_to_usermode+0x26/0x30
[  391.736062]  [<ffffffff8185184e>] retint_user+0x8/0x34
[  391.736941] Code: ff 5b 41 5c 5d c3 48 89 df e8 01 f6 ff ff 48 89 df 31 f6 e8 17 76 ff ff 5b 41 5c 5d c3 48 8b 47 20 4c 8d 60 ff a8 01 4c 0f 44 e7 <41> f6 44 24 08 01 74 08 49 8b 04 24 a8 80 74 1a 48 8b 43 20 a8
[  391.739698] RIP  [<ffffffff811a34dc>] put_compound_page+0x5c/0x1b0
[  391.740571]  RSP <ffff8804292bbcc8>
```

Comment: get_user_pages is fraught with peril, without the rest of the code it's hard to figure out what's causing the fault, also you aren't supposed to simply unmap and put the pages like this if you're flushing the range,  see discussion here https://lwn.net/Articles/753027/

Comment: Crashes how?  What does the kernel oops message say?  Or does it hard lock without an oops?

Comment: @Ahmed, I checked the LWN article, but i have not found how to clear the process cache. I need to dig more.

Comment: Any hints or ideas on how to flush a process cache in Linux kernel?